# Failure to release file debian gitian-builder

Tags: debian

I am attempting to create a fork of PIVX. I have gotten to the stage at which I am ready to create my first build.

According to the gitian-building.md file included in the doc folder:

Gitian needs virtual images of the operating system to build in.
Currently this is Ubuntu Precise for x86_64.
These images will be copied and used every time that a build is started to
make sure that the build is deterministic.
Creating the images will take a while, but only has to be done once.

Execute the following as user `debian`:

`cd gitian-builder
bin/make-base-vm --lxc --arch amd64 --suite precise`

I have done that and receive the following error:

`debian@debian:~/gitian-builder$ bin/make-base-vm -—lxc -—arch amd64 -—suite precise
I: Retrieving  InRelease
I: Retrieving  Release 
E: Failed getting release file http://127.0.0.1:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release`

When I access the URL from my browser the page is still up and running. When I use `wget` Debian has no issues. However when I try to `make-base-vm` I get the above error.

Could this have something to do with the fact that Debian is trying to access the incorrect URL? Why does Debian add the localhost IP to the URL? Is there a way to remove the IP from the URL?

Debian Version: 9.0
Running inside of VirtualBox Version: 5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2)

It may be worth mentioning that I've also tried running the above command with Xenial and Trusty to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It is assumed by gitian that you have apt-cacher-ng installed and running.

Just install it (`apt-get install -y apt-cacher-ng`) and make sure it is running (`service apt-cacher-ng start`) and you should be good.